# Crontab Permission Denied running simple Python Script

Tags: python, bash, cron

I've been trying to get this to work for DAYS. Its doing my head in because everything i search suggests this work.

The process is Cron executes bash which executes python

I open and edit the cron with:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Inside it looks like this:

```
* * * * * /home/pi/cron_bash.sh >> /home/pi/out.txt  2>&1
```

This then feeds through to the bash file which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "$(/home/pi "$0")";
CWD="$(pwd)"
echo $CWD
python /home/pi/cron_log.py
```

The python script is very simple (primairly for debugging process, i'm planning on changing to a script that executes selenium when i've found the issue)-just prints the datetime to a file:

```
from datetime import datetime
dateTimeObj = datetime.now()   
dateStr = dateTimeObj.strftime("%B the %d of %Y is %A at %I:%M %p")
with open('cronlog.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write(dateStr)
```

The problem i have is that the output file (cronlog.txt) doesn't get changed. If i check the out.txt file which should be displaying the log i get this:

```
/home/pi/cron_bash.sh: 2: /home/pi/cron_bash.sh: /home/pi: Permission denied
/root
```

Can anyone help? I don't understand how it could be a permission issue if i'm going through sudo cron, but then again i am a beginner with pi/cron.

Thanks

Felix

Comment: Why does your program need to update a crontab that it doesn't own? Stop using sudo when you don't need to use it. Every user can have a personal crontab (edited with `crontab -e` or updated with `echo "* * * * * somecommandhere" >> /tmp/cronup; crontab /tmp/cronup;`

Comment: I think you misunderstood what the crontab is doing, its launching a bash which launches python. Obviously I tried using the personal crontab first but I ran into the same pwrmission error

Comment: Your `cron_bash.sh` script is nonsense. Fix it first - before you try running it in `cron`.

Answer (score 0):

This line in your script:

```
cd "$(/home/pi "$0")";
```

is trying to execute /home/pi as if it's a program, but it's surely a directory.
What did you mean this line to be?

Comment: Maybe you meant `cd /home/pi`?

Comment: I was actually following the advice from this previously answered question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534135/crontab-not-executing-a-python-script

Comment: But I'm not sure what the cd line does in its entirety, I assumed just change directory

Comment: I think you maybe just want `cd /home/pi` which would change your working directory to the pi user's home directory.
Or `cd $(dirname "$0")` which would change your working directory to the directory where the bash script is.